# Getting data from a custom cell

Tags: uitableview

I am dealing with a problem when I try to get my data from custom cell which has two different textfields. 
The custom cell was implemented this way:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/441/screenshot20120726at434.png/

And the table view looks like this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/screenshot20120726at431.png/

What I want to do is that when I press SAVE button from the right top corner I should get the values from the two textfields and also the switch status. I don't know how to manage the cells in order to do that. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create three index paths with section 0 and rows 0, 1, and 2.  Then ask your table view for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  You know which type of information you want from each -- the same as what you stored in your datasource method -- and can read it from the matching text field or switch.

Comment: Meanwhile I found this kind of solution:   CustomCell *Cell = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];     What do you think about this one? I would like to use 3 kind of those to access my custom cells, in order to get the data from the textfields. Is this what you had in mind?? By the way I am a starter in Objective-C so I probably make lots of mistakes.

Comment: Same approach, yes.  (Going back a step, I have to wonder why you're using a table for this instead of just placing all your information and controls in a regular view...but it should work regardless.)

Comment: The table will be populated with many other attributes from a dictionary which will be stored in a plist. That's why I needed a table because I would like also to remove and add attributes afterward.. But for the beginning I just want to load and save the data. Thank you again!

Comment: Iterating over a table is also possible doing this approach: for ( CustomCell *theTableCell in [[self tableView] visibleCells])  and after that you can iterate over all the cells from the table just like  through an array. You can and something like i=0 before the for and at for's end somethink like i++. Using the value i, you can know what cell from what row are you dealing with. (A switch is wonderful to use: switch(i)....case1...case2..). I did found this solution later. I hope it will help someone.